# Unexpected symbol in read.table

Tags: r

I am trying to read data with:

```
data <- read.table('pwaves.txt', header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep='\t')
```

Works ok,except I got X in front of each number.Like this:

```
      X5   X6   X7
fcm 13.0 12.5 11.8
gk  10.9 10.5 10.2
gg  12.0 11.0 10.8
```

Why?

Comment: What does the first line of `pwaves.txt` look like?

Comment: You can't have column names that begin with numeric literals.

Comment: Set `check.names = FALSE`, but be warned that this makes other stuff harder because you won't have valid column names anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it because your headers are numeric, R checks this and transforms it.
Try to add check.names=FALSE

```
     data <- read.table('pwaves.txt', header=TRUE, row.names=1, check.names=FALSE, sep='\t')
```